# Is there any easy algorithm to do edge coloring on a complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

For a given complete graph $G$ having $n$ nodes, how can we build a edge coloring of 
$G$ with $n$ colors.

Comment: Finding the "optimal" coloring (with the lowest number) is NP-hard, so for an arbitrary *n* that will result in backtracking.

Comment: you have to visit every edges of the graph, try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043060/algorithm-to-traverse-all-edges-in-a-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Just color the edge i,j with the color number i+j.
You will need n-1 colors.

Comment: Assuming you mean `i+j mod n` (otherwise you would need `2n-1` colors): this needs `n` colors, not `n-1`. Consider the complete graph `G` with 3 vertices. Obviously you need 3 colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the graph as a sports tournament where each node is a team, each edge is a match, and each color is a round. You are then looking for a round-robin tournament and can use the circle method ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_method)) to find the coloring:

> The circle method is the standard algorithm to create a schedule for a round-robin tournament. All competitors are assigned to numbers, and then paired in the first round:
>
> **Round 1. (1 plays 14, 2 plays 13, ... )**
>
> Next, one of the competitors in the first or last column of the table is fixed (number one in this example) and the others rotated clockwise one position
>
> **Round 2. (1 plays 13, 14 plays 12, ... )**
>
> **Round 3. (1 plays 12, 13 plays 11, ... )**
>
> This is repeated until you end up almost back at the initial position:
>
> **Round 13. (1 plays 2, 3 plays 14, ... )**

For `n` even this leads to a coloring with `n - 1` colors.

The standard round-robin approach to deal with an odd number of teams is to add a dummy team. So for `n` odd there is one additional round and you'll get a coloring with `n` colors.